# Weakening conditions on the Borel-Cantelli lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The Borel-Cantelli states that if there is a countable collection of measurable sets $E_n$ such that $\sum m(E_n) < \infty$, then $m(\limsup E_n)=0$.

Is it possible to obtain the same conclusion but with a weaker condition; namely can we require simply that $m(E_n) \rightarrow 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition $m(E_n)\to 0$ is too weak. One counterexample on the unit interval with Lebesgue measure is the sequence of sets $E_1=[0,1)$, $E_2=[0,1/2)$, $E_3=[1/2,1)$, $E_4=[0,1/3)$, $E_5=[1/3,2/3)$, $E_6=[2/3,1)$, $E_7=[0,1/4)$, $E_8=[1/4,2/4)$, etc. Every number in $[0,1)$ is seen infinitely often among the $E_n$, but their measure tends to zero.